# Net::HTTP.get encoding in ruby-on-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, character-encoding

I'm doing a simple get to an URL and I get back some encoding that I'm just not able to crack.

`res_str=Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse("http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=youtube&ds=yt&q=s%C3%A1lin"))`

my response is something like this

> window.google.ac.h(["s�lin",[["s�lin hans j�ns m�ns",0],["s�lin hans
>   j�ns m�ns undir ��num �hrifum",0],["s�lin hans j�ns m�ns �� fullkomnar
>   mig",0],["s�lin",0],["s�lin hans j�ns m�ns s�d�ma",0],["s�lin hans
>   j�ns m�ns hj� ��r",0],["s�lin hans j�ns m�ns hvar er
>   draumurinn",0],["s�lin hans j�ns m�ns original",0],["s�lin hans j�ns
>   m�ns ef �g �tti",0],["s�lin hans j�ns m�ns okkar
>   n�tt",0]],{"q":"A9gr8ZE66_XaaFyUIlaNLEwyxQU","k":1}])

however, if I test my url in postman i get the result I would like

> window.google.ac.h(["sálin",[["sálin hans jóns míns",0],["sálin hans
>   jóns míns undir þínum áhrifum",0],["sálin hans jóns míns þú fullkomnar
>   mig",0],["sálin",0],["sálin hans jóns míns sódóma",0],["sálin hans
>   jóns míns hjá þér",0],["sálin hans jóns míns hvar er
>   draumurinn",0],["sálin hans jóns míns original",0],["sálin hans jóns
>   míns ef ég ætti",0],["sálin hans jóns míns okkar
>   nótt",0]],{"q":"ecnVzf6wE6HskDep7UOiRxxu5_4","k":1}])

When I execute my get in irb:

`res_str=Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse("http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?Client=youtube&ds=yt&q=s%C3%A1lin"))`

I get the following:

> "window.google.ac.h([\"s\xE1lin\",[[\"s\xE1lin hans j\xF3ns m\xEDns\",0],[\"s\xE1lin hans j\xF3ns m\xEDns undir \xFE\xEDnum
>   \xE1hrifum\",0],[\"s\xE1lin hans j\xF3ns m\xEDns \xFE\xFA fullkomnar
>   mig\",0],[\"s\xE1lin\",0],[\"s\xE1lin hans j\xF3ns m\xEDns
>   s\xF3d\xF3ma\",0],[\"s\xE1lin hans j\xF3ns m\xEDns hj\xE1
>   \xFE\xE9r\",0],[\"s\xE1lin hans j\xF3ns m\xEDns hvar er
>   draumurinn\",0],[\"s\xE1lin hans j\xF3ns m\xEDns
>   original\",0],[\"s\xE1lin hans j\xF3ns m\xEDns ef \xE9g
>   \xE6tti\",0],[\"s\xE1lin hans j\xF3ns m\xEDns okkar
>   n\xF3tt\",0]],{\"q\":\"zLVSFcDtEbR_JBE4te2_XjMOeRs\",\"k\":1}])"

what can I do when executing the request or when I handle the response to get the true response?

> "window.google.ac.h([\"sálin\",[[\"sálin hans jóns míns\",0],[\"sálin hans jóns míns etc....

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out :) I just had to set the user agent in order to receive UTF-8 encoded results like this

```
    # escape the query
    q=URI::escape(params["q"])
    # prepare request 
    uri = URI.parse("http://clients1.google.com/complete/search?client=youtube&q="<<q)
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
    request["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0"
    # make request
    response = http.request(request)
    # read body
    body = response.body
```

Now I get the correctly encoding results. However, I try returning the results as json using `render :json => results` and the results coming to the browser still shows a few � unfortunately. I will comment on this when I figure that out :)

**EDIT:**
Done! I'm working with the results and adding the suggestions to an array directly from the body but what I need to do is force the encoding to UTF-8

```
    body = body[body.index('(')..body.index('{')]    
    body.scan(/"([^"]*)"/).to_a.each { |r| results.push r[0].force_encoding(::Encoding::UTF_8) }
    results = results[1..results.length].map {|v| v }
```

Now I'm getting the results correctly to the browser :) Hope this helps someone.